# How can I perform following operation in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, transformation, summarize

I have a data frame with columns

```
full_name   flag
XYZ yes
XYZ missing
XYZ yes
ABC yes
```

I first want to group by full_name, find the sum of flag values and then count no of 'yes'
expected output -

```
full_name flag num den
XYZ yes 2 3
XYZ missing 2 3
XYZ yes 2 3
ABC yes 1 1
```

I have tried using summarize but it groups the names and gives the sum - I want the sum value to be added for each row. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: `summarize()` gives one row per group, `mutate()` adds columns with the same number of rows.